# How do I show an iOS 13 SwiftUI View from the AppDelegate?

Tags: ios, swift, ios13

In my app I've got actions so `application(_:performActionFor:completionHandler:)` is called when it's executed.  Previously it was grabbing the storyboard and showing the right `UIViewController`.  How, in iOS 13, do I grab the appropriate SwiftUI `View` and display that instead?

Comment: It’s unclear what issue you are having. Please update your question with more details.

Comment: When the app delegate method is called, how do you instantiate an iOS 13 SwiftUI `View`.  For storyboards I'd just instantiate `UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)` and then call `present` against the root view.  How do I do the equivalent in iOS 13 with scenes?

Comment: Implement the corresponding scene delegate method.

Comment: Which one?  I don't see anything in `UISceneDelegate` that seems to correspond to an action.

Comment: Look at `UIWindowSceneDelegate`.

Comment: Thanks!  Don't know how I missed that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197702/discussion-between-gargoyle-and-rmaddy).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode 11 & iOS13, using UIKIT can't change background colour of UIViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58251425/xcode-11-ios13-using-uikit-cant-change-background-colour-of-uiviewcontroller)