# Xcode 11 & iOS13, using UIKIT can't change background colour of UIViewController

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, ios13, xcode11

So I created a new project in Xcode11, set the AppDelegate to my new VC and commented the code present in xxx scene delegate to not have the UIKit part:

```swift
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        window = UIWindow()
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        let controller = MainVC()
        window?.rootViewController = controller
        return true
    }
```

In my UIViewController I wanted to set the background colour,

```swift
import UIKit

class MainVC : UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        self.view.backgroundColor = .blue
        print("main Screen showing")
        ConfigureUI()
        setupUI()

    }
```

But the result is a blackScreen in Simulator. Not even taking the code from other projects would help...
I've done this before in the other Xcode versions and should had work. Any ideas?

PS: The App gets in the ViewController, I can print in the console, but the screen is black.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> and commented the code present in xxx scene delegate to not have the UIKit part

You mustn't do that. It is *your* code that needs to go in the right place. If you make a new project in Xcode 11, this code does nothing:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    window = UIWindow()
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    let controller = MainVC()
    window?.rootViewController = controller
    return true
}
```

The code *runs*, but the window property is not your app's window, so what you're doing is pointless. The window now belongs to the *scene delegate*. That is where you need to create the window and set its root view controller.

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, 
    willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, 
    options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            self.window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene) 
            let vc = MainVC()                                  
            self.window!.rootViewController = vc             
            self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()                 
        }
}
```

Comment: Hello @matt Sir, I have used above code for initially when app launch, But I'm confused how to used this code after login and required to set home view controller.

Comment: @SagarChauhan https://github.com/mattneub/RegistrationExample