# Presenting tabBarController on iOS 13

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, ios13

I'm trying to present a tabbar controller programmatically using the two methods below: ( but both methods are failing).

```
var window: UIWindow?
let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let myTabBar = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "happy")
window?.rootViewController = myTabBar
```

I tested it on iOS 12, it works. But, when changing to iOS 13, it doesn't.

Another method: ( not tested on iOS 12).

```
let newVC = tabBarController?.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "okplz")
 tabBarController?.present(newVC!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

[image: storyboard]

Comment: I'm assuming you're setting the rootviewcontroller in the appDelegate?  In iOS 13 you need to set it in SceneDelegate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode 11 & iOS13, using UIKIT can't change background colour of UIViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58251425/xcode-11-ios13-using-uikit-cant-change-background-colour-of-uiviewcontroller)

Comment: thanks, man! that was an easy, great fix! I've added it in the ScenceDelegte instead of  appDelegate.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add the code in the SceneDelegate instead of appDelegte as answered by @valosip.