# Can't set initial ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to navigate into the Home page, when I have stored access token, but it doesn't work. It always directs me to LoginViewController on launching.

Currently I am using this code:

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        let accessToken: String? = KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: "accessToken")
        if accessToken != nil
        {
            let mainStoryboard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let homePage = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController
            self.window?.rootViewController = homePage                
        }

        return true
    }
```

User interface of project: Storyboard

Swift: 5

Xcode: 11.4

Target deployment: 13.4

Comment: No, it is too old answer.

Comment: I found solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59563489/set-rootviewcontroller-programmatically-not-working-picking-initial-view-contro

Answer (score 1):

Try this

in my app: it is working

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
var nvc: UINavigationController? = nil

nvc  = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NavRootVC") as? UINavigationController

let objCntrl : HomeVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeVC") as! HomeVC
nvc?.viewControllers = [objCntrl]
window?.rootViewController = nvc
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I replaced `NavRootVC` and `HomeVC` with `HomeViewController`. Why do you use two different identifiers?

Comment: Don't replace "NavRootVC". Only replace "HomeViewController". and try again.

Comment: `Thread 1: Exception: "Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: 0x282f1cde0>) doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'NavRootVC'"`

Comment: what is your navigation controller class name?

Comment: I am not using any navigation controller... :)

Comment: Then this code is not working. You need to add Navigation Controller.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because you haven't initialized the window property.
You just have to add these two lines

```
self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

after `let homePage = mainStoryboard ...`

Comment: I tried to add this line, but anyway it doesn't work.

Comment: yes check my ediitted answer

Comment: It didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

```
   let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
   let homePage = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as? HomeViewController

   let objNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: homePage ?? UIViewController())
   self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
   window?.rootViewController = objNavigationController
   window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Comment: `Cannot convert value of type 'HomeViewController.Type' to expected argument type 'UIViewController?'`

Comment: Shouldn't that be `rootViewController: homePage` ?

Comment: See edited  changes done at this line 
`(rootViewController: homePage ?? UIViewController())`

Comment: It didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

If your deployment target > 13
then you should go with `SceneDelegate`. you can access `window` property in SceneDelegate.

set your rootViewController in this method

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

        guard let window  = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }

}
```

This key should be added in your plist
[image]

Comment: Application Scene Manifest already exist in Info.plist, but I don't know how to convert whole project into SwiftUI.